# Pass a File object to a Python script from Java, then get the outputted result as a new File object

Tags: java, python

I'm working on a big Java project right now, and I decided that the easiest way to "fix" an issue I have with the data in a `File` object would be to parse and edit it with a Python script I wrote. I tested the Python script on its own on this particular file (outside of Java) and it works fine. Now I'm just wondering how I integrate my Python script with the rest of my Java code.

I basically want to somehow pass this `File` object to my Python script, which has to be called from Java. Then I want to take the file that the Python script outputs, read it back in as a `File` object, and return that from this particular Java method.

From researching a bit, I've heard Jython come up a bit, as well as the built-in Python interpreter in Java 6 and later. I'm just not sure where to start. Or alternatively, I guess I could port this Python script over to Java, but that's kind of a last resort. Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Why don't you program it in one language? Sounds to me like you're overcomplicating the things here.

Comment: I agree.  You should do one language.  if this is not an option you could use a Process to execute a different command on your OS firing off your python change.  This is not OS independent though and can be directly affected by your environment running the application.

Comment: Look at these classes
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Process.html
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Runtime.html
But I think you'd better do it in just one language.

Comment: @peter.petrov "Why don't you program it in one language?" If the script was already there, it'd rather be an overcomplication to rewrite it in Java.

Comment: Is there a reason you want to pass the "File object" around specifically?  A more standard workflow would be to invoke the python interpreter from Java, have the python script write the file somewhere and then exit, with your java program then reading the file in.

Comment: You can also make the Python script read from STDIN and write to STDOUT. Then you can feed in the file from Java through a pipe and read the result back through a pipe as well.

Comment: Everyone has made good points here about doing it in Java vs. passing the data to Python. Hypothetically, if I were to port my script over to Java, what would be the general workflow for parsing this `File` object?

Answer (score 1):

Look at these classes

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Process.html
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Runtime.html

You can use them in Java to call your Python process.

Comment: Especially note `Process#getOutputStream()` and `Process#getInputStream()`. You can communicate with the script through those channels (they are represented as `sys.stdout` and `sys.stdin` on the Python side)